# Multiple hypothesis ANOVA

Tags: anova, clustering, meta-analysis

I'm not sure that I've titled this question correctly, but here is my query.

Suppose you are given a set of measurements and the uncertainty (variance) associated with each. The task is to statistically figure out how many different objects were likely measured and finally, to combine measurements into a single estimate for each.

The second part is easy enough - an uncertainty-weighted mean would do it - but I am having difficulty understanding how to sort out how many objects were measured. If there were just two objects, ANOVA would work. But what if there are an unknown number of objects?

As an aside, I'm aware of a Baysian technique in which one considers each measurement in turn, building a set of hypotheses for each measurement that doesn't fall within the confidence interval of an existing hypothesis and combining it into the hypothesis when they do. But I think this method is dependent on the order the measurements are considered and therefore imparts a kind of time dependence on measurements that have none.

I feel like this is something that's commonly done and I should know how to do, but I'm stumped so any thoughts you all might have would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be a **finite mixture model** with an unknown number of components. A set of measurements and their variances sounds like **meta-analysis**. I suggest you have at look at [Peter Schlattmann's webpage for his book 'Medical Applications of Finite Mixture Models'](http://www.charite.de/biometrie/schlattmann/book/), which includes meta-analysis amongst its applications. The book is not cheap, but if you download the R or SAS code from that webpage and have a look at the documentation you *may* be able to manage without it.

Comment: Am I too naive thinking that, _maybe_, discriminant analysis could be employed here?